# Ubuntu 10.04.2 - PATH not working in desktop environment, working in terminals

Tags: ubuntu, path

I need to add a directory entry to PATH env. var.

I added at the end of both of my ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile the line `export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/apps/...`. The change is working for terminal sessions but it's not working for the graphical environment. When I start a certain application via it's icon it's complaining that it can't find a certain dependent program in the path (it's working normally if started from the terminal). I tried logging off/on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.profile`, and remove the statement from `.bashrc`.

Comment: will it then work for terminals as well?